# How to add attributes to NFT during minting in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, nft

I have a code in Solidity to mint a NFT.

When code is executed, I have a visible NFT on testnets.opensea.io.
But I would like to see on OpenSea the attributes name and surname entered in my smart contract.
This surname and first name change regularly. I want to do this dynamically.

Is it possible ? How ?

Thanks !

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
 
contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
 
    struct Reward{
        string name,
        string surname
    }
    Reward[] rewards;
 
    constructor() ERC721 ("MyNFT", "MYN") {}
 
    function mint(address _user, string memory _tokenURI, string memory _name, string memory _surname) public returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
    rewards.push(Reward(_name, _surname));
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(_user, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI);
 // what about _name & _surname added to the NFT ???
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you modified the metadata JSON file, and you want this change reflected on OpenSea.

After you modified the file, you need to call their endpoint [Refresh NFT Metadata](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/refresh-nft-metadata) so that they can register the change.

*Note: They might reflect the new metadata with a delay.*